# Export a boolean value with react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this hook and I need export a const with an boolean value, this way is sending a string.

```
export const useType = () => {
  
    const isFoo = 'string';
    const isBar = 'other_string';
  
    return { isFoo, isBar };
  };
```

How can I transform this in an boolean value?

I'm new, Thanks if anyone can help me

Comment: Too little info to answer really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but you mean this?

```
export const useType = () => {
  
    const isFoo = 'string';
    const isBar = 'other_string';
    const iAmBoolean = true;
  
    return { isFoo, isBar, iAmBoolean };
  };
```

Comment: for example, 'other_string'; it is a value that I have already returned from another check, but the const isBar remains as a string and I need to check if it is this value and return true

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you need to check if a value is an string equivelent to isFoo and isBar.

```
export const useType = (props) => {
 if(props === 'isFoo'){
 return true
}else{
 return false
}
}

//then you call useType(varWithTheString) to check if it's Foo or not.
```